# Calling variables inside functions in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a function as shown below

```
fun1 <- function(){
  list(
    EXP ='selectInput',HOW  ='selectInput',
    WHAT = 'selectInput',WHERE = 'selectInput'
  )
}
```

This is repeated many times in my code so I am planning to declare variables here

```
e <- "EXP"
a <- "HOW"
b <- "WHAT"
c <- "WHERE"
```

Expected OUtput

```
fun1 <- function(){
  list(
    e ='selectInput',a  ='selectInput',
    b = 'selectInput',c = 'selectInput'
  )
}

fun1()
$EXP
[1] "selectInput"

$HOW
[1] "selectInput"

$WHAT
[1] "selectInput"

$WHERE
[1] "selectInput"
```

But the output I am getting is

```
> fun1 <- function(){
   list(
     e ='selectInput',a  ='selectInput',
     b = 'selectInput',c = 'selectInput'
   )
 }
> fun1()
$e
[1] "selectInput"

$a
[1] "selectInput"

$b
[1] "selectInput"

$c
[1] "selectInput"
```

So can we call variables inside the functions

Answer (score 0):

list takes the parameter name literally, it's not like in a Python dict where any hashable value can be a key, they are 1-indexed or named*.

You can do something like

```
fun1 <- function() {
  setNames(
    list("selectInput", "selectInput", "selectInput", "selectInput"), 
    c(e, a, b, c)
  )
}
```

* You can use numbers by escaping them with backticks but that turns them into `character` because `names` are `character`.